# Checkers Game on Mac 10.4.11

Tags: games

I need to install Checkers game on my Mac 10.4.11 for my HCI project. Does anyone know a free download link?

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a 1.99 checkers game in the mac app store named aptly, [checkers](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id402380776?mt=12).
Also, have you considered just playing it online? There might be some flash based checkers games you could download and run locally.

Comment: tnx, I used it, it works :)

Comment: Glad to see one of these worked out!

Answer (score 0):

There's not much out there!  Those that are work on 10.5 and 10.6 but not 10.4

[This](http://www.tranquilapps.com/) one is $4.99 and works on 10.4

Might be your only hope.

Comment: I could not open this link, could u send it to me again?

Comment: http://www.tranquilapps.com/   opens for me fine

Answer (score 0):

[Big Bang Checkers](http://www.freeverse.com/bigbangchess/) from Freeverse works on Tiger (or used to). It comes with a package with other games **but** it costs 25$ (a little bit too much given that you were looking for a *free* link).

You can find more information about it at [MacUpdate's page for BigBang](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14969/big-bang-board-games):

> Big Bang Board Games... It's Sun vs. Moon in these innovative takes on great classic games. Play Checkers, Chess, Reversi, Mancala, Backgammon, 4-in-a-Row and Tic-Tac-Toe against the animated computer opponents, via email with friends, or online with new friends from around the globe!

In their requirements site it says:

> REQUIREMENTS
>   PPC / Intel, Mac OS X 10.3 or later.

Since I have it, let me show you a sshot:

[image]

*<sub>**Note**: Freeverse seem to be having a MySQL problem in their website at this time</sub>*